# Pandas: Merging 2 different size dataframes with different columns along 1 shared column

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen other answered questions similar to this one, but to my knowledge I have yet to find a response that does exactly what I am looking for. I have 2 pandas dataframes: `df1` which has 3 columns-`ID`, `A`, and `B`; and `df2` which has 4 columns-`ID`, `C`, `D`, and `E`.

`df1` has the following rows:

```
   ID    A    B
0   1  200  0.5
1   1  201  0.5
2   2   99  1.1
```

And `df2` has the following rows:

```
   ID   C       D   E
0   1  50  1.1250   0
1   1  52  1.1300   0
2   1  50  1.1200   0
3   2  25  0.6667  20
4   2  24  0.6667  20
```

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` on the `ID` column such that if a pair of rows from each dataframe has a matching ID, we combine them into a single row. Notice that the dataframes are not the same size. If one dataframe has a row with no more available matches from the other dataframe, then we fill in the missing data with `NaN`.  **How can I accomplish this merge in pandas?**

So far, I have tried variations of the function `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='...')`, but no matter if I put how= 'left', 'right', 'outer', or 'inner', I get a [wrong result which is a dataframe with 8 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TW3p.png). Below is the desired result.

**Desired result:**

```
   ID    A    B   C       D   E
0   1  200  0.5  50  1.1250   0
1   1  201  0.5  52  1.1300   0
2   1  NaN  NaN  50  1.1200   0
3   2   99  1.1  25  0.6667  20
4   2  NaN  NaN  24  0.6667  20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order your ID using `groupby` ID and `cumcount` so that first ID 1 in df1 joins with the first ID 1 in df2 and the 2nd to 2nd, and so on. And the same with ID 2 and so on for all IDs in both dataframes.  Then, `merge` on both ID and key with `how='outer'`.

```
df1k = df1.assign(key=df1.groupby('ID').cumcount())
df2k = df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('ID').cumcount())

df_out = df1k.merge(df2k, on=['ID','key'], how='outer').sort_values('ID')
```

Output:

```
   ID      A    B  key   C       D   E
0   1  200.0  0.5    0  50  1.1250   0
1   1  201.0  0.5    1  52  1.1300   0
3   1    NaN  NaN    2  50  1.1200   0
2   2   99.0  1.1    0  25  0.6667  20
4   2    NaN  NaN    1  24  0.6667  20
```

And, you can drop the 'key' also,

```
df_out.drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID      A    B   C       D   E
0   1  200.0  0.5  50  1.1250   0
1   1  201.0  0.5  52  1.1300   0
3   1    NaN  NaN  50  1.1200   0
2   2   99.0  1.1  25  0.6667  20
4   2    NaN  NaN  24  0.6667  20
```